# Scrapy - why change tabs selector?

Tags: scrapy

I'm just starting to use scrapy and I'm stuck ... I would like to be able to make my script navigate between tabs but I can not find any tutorials that explain how. I thank you in advance for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsOZq.png)

Comment: Your question is very broad and it's impossible to answer it. You should reformat it to be more specific.

To give you a bit of general info - it depends on tabs, some tabs are in html and are switched around by javascript, while some do external AJAX requests to fill in the data with javascript when you click it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The buttons execute an ajax query. here is the associated html code. ```<a href="/ajax/sets/altImages?setID=26649" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">More images
<mark>35</mark>
</a>```

Comment: you should probably give us the link to the page in question and someone might help more. Also, you should try to google more before asking, because things like this have been answered alot.

Comment: Do you have a link to the answer because I looked on google but I did not find anything ...